# Create a column with the column name of the max value of the row in R

Tags: r

I got this data:

```
df = data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = c(5,1,4))
>   x y
> 1 1 5
> 2 2 1
> 3 3 4
```

But i want a new column with the column name of the max value in the row

like this:

```
>   x y max.col
> 1 1 5    y
> 2 2 1    x
> 3 3 4    y
```

I've tried a lot of codes, but without sucess. Extra points with i can use the solution with %>%

Edit1: i got a lot of NA's and i want skip it

Edit2: i got 30 different columns in the real df

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `max.col` to return the index of the `max` value and use that to subset the column name.  If there are `NA`s replace the `NA` with a negative value

If a row is all `NA`, then we can identify it with `rowSums` on logical matrix

```
i1 <- !rowSums(!is.na(df))

df$max.col <- names(df)[max.col(replace(df, is.na(df), -999), 'first')]
df$max.col[i1] <- NA
```

Comment: i'm getting some trouble with NA's. If row = c(1,2,3,4,NA), it returns NA.

Comment: @BryanSouza you could replace with a negative value

Comment: Ok. cool! but this NA is important for me. Later i will need to back with it. but i can do this

Comment: @BryanSouza I am not replacing the original data.  It is just the replacement on the fly with `replace(df, is.na(df), -999)` you can check the `df` output

Comment: I got more one problem. if all my columns are NA (no records), it returns the name of the first column, while it should be NA or 0 or anything detectable.

Comment: i wanna be like you when i grow up

Comment: @BryanSouza On a serious note, i think anybody can become a master in coding.  It just needs some daily practise.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution for your question

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(max.col = ifelse(x>y, "x", "y"))
#   x y max.col
# 1 1 5       y
# 2 2 1       x
# 3 3 4       y
```

Comment: Nice, but i got a lot of columns and NA values